# I am new to programming

Tags: c++

https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1047
I cant find error anyone can help me ?!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a,b,c,d,h,m;

    cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
    h = c-a;
    m = d-b;

    if (h<0)
    {
        h=24+(c-a);
    }

    if(m<0)
    {
        m=60+(d-b);
        h--;
    }

    if(a==c && b==d)
    {
        cout<<"O JOGO DUROU 24 HORA(S) E 0 MINUTO(S)"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"O JOGO DUROU "<<h<<" HORA(S) E "<<m<<" MINUTO(S)"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: might help if you tell people what kind of errors you're getting and what kinds of things you've tried in fixing them

Comment: You need to say what the code tries to do, what is the expected behavior vs the observed behavior and copy-paste compiler errors if any.

Comment: `if(m<0)` This needs to be checked *before* `if(h<0)` (why?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert all to minutes before subtracting the end time for the start time.

If the end time is smaller than the start time, it means it started one day and ended another. This case is handled in the `if` statement.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a,b,c,d;

    cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
    int start_time = a * 60 + b;
    int end_time  =  c * 60 + d;

    int duration = end_time - start_time;
    if(start_time >= end_time) duration = (24 * 60 - (start_time - end_time));  

    cout<<"O JOGO DUROU "<<(duration / 60)<<" HORA(S) E "<<(duration % 60)<<" MINUTO(S)"<<endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*One* data set that will cause an issue, starting at `10:15` and finishing at `10:14` the following day (or, I suspect, *any* duration between `23:01` and `23:59`).

Running those values through you code (slightly reduced and reformatted, but functionally the same):

```
cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;     // a=10, b=15, c=10, d=14
h = c - a;                   // h=0
m = d - b;                   // m=-1
if (h < 0)                   // false
    h = 24 + (c - a);
if (m < 0)                   // tru
    m = 60 + (d - b);        // m=59
    h--;                     // h=-1, that's not right :-)
```

You can fix that quite easily just by doing the "minute less than zero" processing first. That way, the hour will never end up at `-1`:

```
if (m < 0) {
    m += 60
    h--;
}
if (h < 0) {
    h += 24
}
if (h == 0 && m == 0) {
    h = 24;
}

cout << "O JOGO DUROU " << h << " HORA(S) E " << m << " MINUTO(S)" << '\n';
```

You'll see I've also simplified some of the assignments (with `+=`) and removed the need for two separate `cout` statements by adjusting `0, 0` to become `24, 0`.